# Want to recreate the following UI for a time lapse (timeline)

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to recreate the following:

and I have the following code which has the gist of it, but not the exact look and feel, and I am still trying to get the hang of the UI aspects of Swift.

```
    VStack(spacing: 30) {

        Group {

            VStack {
                
                HStack {
                
                    Image(systemName: "2.circle")
                
                    Text("Jan 2th, 2021 at 2:34 PM") 
                
                }

                HStack {
                    
                    
                    Divider()
                    
                    VStack {
                        
                        Text("Title here")
                        
                        Text("Notes here")
                        
                        Text("Item not tracked on this day")
                        
                    }

                }.frame(height: 200)

            }
            
        }
        
    }
```

Can anymore provide a better way of mirroring the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is possible solution. Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

[image: demo]

```
var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 30) {
        
        HStack(alignment: .top) {
            
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "2.circle")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                HStack {
                    Divider()
                }
            }
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Jan 2th, 2021 at 2:34 PM").padding(.bottom)
                Text("Title here")
                    .font(.title).bold()
                Text("Notes here")
                    .font(.title3).bold().padding(.bottom)
                Text("Item not tracked on this day")
            }
        }
        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: the alignment is centered, how would i make sure its to the left, or leading when its displayed?

Comment: Add to root container `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)`